# The name of the array as a method parameter

Tags: android, arrays, methods

I'm trying to create a private void method where I extract data from arrays. One of the method parameters is the array name.

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrayName));
```

Android Studio cannot resolve symbol “arrayName”.
How do I correctly enter a parameter in a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send arrayId instead arrayName

```
loadArray(R.array.arrayName);

private void loadArray(int arrayId) {

}
```